# Aptana installation error: failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file crc error

Tags: node.js, aptana3

I am trying to install Aptana Studio 3.6.1 on a windows 10 machine and I get the following error:

failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file crc error

I downloaded and installed node js 64 bit version and got the same error. Then I tried downloading and installing the 32 bit version to see if that made a difference and got the same error.  I have looked at all other solutions on  stackoverflow and none work. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing on my new laptop (even though installing the current Node.js worked on my previous laptop, it wouldn't work on this new one): An older version of Node.js worked for me this time around: http://titanium-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/nodejs/node-v0.10.13-x86.msi